# How to get error messages from pdflatex tool (specially running from php)

Tags: errors, pdftex, logging

I am executing pdflatex from php script and it gives me very long list of log entries mixed with errors e.g

```
 system('/usr/texbin/pdflatex    -output-directory=./temp/tex '.$tex_output  . "   1> /dev/null  ",$firstRun);
```

[log output](http://paste2.org/p/2480960)

Is it possible to get errors or warnings only (may be using logs files it generates ) ?

Comment: Well, `cat filename.log | grep -iB2 -A5 "error\|warning"` However, the log file you linked seems to be missing end-of-line characters, which is not a fault of TeX.

Comment: The output can be minimized using option `--interaction=batchmode`. The exit code of the command is set, if there were any errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error always starts with `<exclamationmark><space>`, which should be easy to look for in the log.

As well, you can pipe something like `x\nx\n` to the program `latex`, which should make it stop after first error. Then you can search it even easier, I believe that the last empty line in the log should be just after this error. (This is because after you e`x`it after an error, only some final font information and memory usage is written into the log.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up writing for Node.js. Here is the command:

```
pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode -halt-on-error my-doc.tex
```

The code to parse the error from `stdout`:

```
function parseError(text: string) {
  let lines = text.trim().split('\n')
  let firstErrorFound = false
  let lastErrorFound = false
  let message: Array<string> = []

  let newLineCount = 0

  lines.forEach(line => {
    if (line.match(/^\!/)) {
      if (firstErrorFound) {
        lastErrorFound = true
      }
      firstErrorFound = true
    }

    if (lastErrorFound) {
      return
    }

    if (firstErrorFound) {
      // don't have more than 2 new lines in a row.
      if (line.match(/^\s*$/)) {
        newLineCount++

        if (newLineCount > 1) {
          return
        }
      } else {
        newLineCount = 0
      }

      if (line.match(/See the LaTeX manual/i)) {
        return
      }

      if (line.match(/Type\s+H <return>\s+for immediate help/i)) {
        return
      }

      if (line.match(/^\s+\.\.\.\s*/)) {
        return
      }

      message.push(line.replace(/^\!\s+/, '').replace(/\s*$/, ''))
    }
  })

  return message.join('\n').replace(/\n\n+/gm, '\n\n')
}
```

Example output:

```
LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble.

l.3 \usepackage
              {geometry}
```